# Django response giving CORS error for an AJAX request

Tags: django, ajax, wordpress, django-rest-framework

I'm a beginner in Django and WordPress and I'm making an API request from HTML-Javascript code which is added to my WordPress page.
API request was successfully sent and processed in Django-rest-framework backend, but the response is giving me CORS errors

**Errors on console**

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/videogen/' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

> POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/videogen/ net::ERR_FAILED
> send    @   jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2
> ajax    @   jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2
> paraSubmit  @   (index):373
> onsubmit    @   (index):435
>
> XHR failed loading: POST "http://127.0.0.1:8000/videogen/". send @
> jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2 ajax @ jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2 paraSubmit @
> (index):373 onsubmit @ (index):435

**HTML CODE BLOCK IN MY WORDPRESS PAGE**

```
<script>
function paraSubmit(event){
event.preventDefault();

 // creating JSON data to send..

$.ajax({
  url : 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/videogen/',
  type: "POST",
  crossDomain: true,
  data: data,
  dataType   : "json",
  success    : function(response){
      console.log(response);
      alert("Video generated and sent!!");
  },
  error : function(response){
      console.log(response);
    //   alert("Video not created" );
  }
  });
}

</script>



<form onsubmit="paraSubmit(event)" id="paragraph-form" >
    <input type="text" id="para-name" name="name" placeholder="Name" required/>
    <input type="text" id="para-email" name="Email" placeholder="Email" required/>
    <textarea id="paragraph" placeholder="Enter Paragraph here" required></textarea>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-small">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**settings.py on Django backend**

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGIN_REGEXES = [
r"^http://127.0.0.1:[0-9]{1,4}$",
r"^https://127.0.0.1:[0-9]{1,4}$"
]
```

The Request is processed and the result is successfully generated on the backend.
The Response is sent with a status code of 201 from the backend.

**response printed on console**

```
status: 0 
statusCode: ƒ (e) 
statusText: "error"
```

**Please help me resolve this error.
Please let me know if you need anything else.**

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this django library

https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/

Install it, and then add in the `settings.py` the url of your application

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "https://example.com",
    "http://localhost:5000"
]
```

Note: If you are not using port 80 (HTTP) or 443 (HTTPS) you will need to specifically include the port number.

Comment: I'm already using this and I still get the error.

Comment: This solution worked for me